# Owl Carousel not working after uploading to the server

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

My Owl Carousel, previously installed on this theme: https://w3layouts.com/beauty-salon-beauty-category-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/ isn't working after I uploaded it to the host.

I tried to update `owl.carousel.js` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any errors or warnings in DevTools console?

Comment: have you made sure all corresponding js files have been uploaded to the server?